# How to restrict access to a resource based on frequency of access?

Tags: key-management, access-control, databases

I want to restrict access to a particular resource based on time (configurable). So suppose user A has time t configured from him. He can access the resource only once every t time units. The values of t can be from a fixed set but not a very small set. I was thinking of using multiple hash chains to encrypt the data, but I am looking for something more scalable.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Hash chains are not equal to encryption. What data are you trying to encrypt and why? How is encryption related to time limitations? Who's the bad guy in your scenario?

Comment: I referred to hash chains to generate keys that will then be used for encryption.

Comment: The Bad guy here would be someone trying to read the values more frequently than he is supposed to.

Answer (score 2):

This depends on whether the user can store the resource locally after accessing it once, thus circumventing any frequency access control. This is why most forms of client-side encryption can't protect against software piracy or pay-per-view siphoning.

If the resource is a server resource, a simple register tracking the user's last access should suffice for throttling the service.

There are complex tricks that can manipulate user consumption of subscription-based media*, but none are easy. Hash chaining/nested encryption relies on the ability to purge the decrypted content or keys to stop excessive frequency of use.

So an answer: **Put all or part of the resource on a server to control frequency of access.**

<sub>* [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19150441/using-a-proof-of-work-system-to-discourage-piracy-or-encourage-donations) for example ;-)</sub>

Comment: The resource is something that changes every few milliseconds..And there might be a scenario where I want to let user A see the values every 5 seconds and user B every 2 seconds.

Comment: @RuchirPatwa So this dynamic resource is provided by a server you control?

Comment: Yes its from a server I control

Comment: @RuchirPatwa Then this is an implementation question (how to throttle requests per known user) and will get the best answer if asked on the `stackoverflow` stack exchange site.